# Is there a way to have logcheck send a daily digest as well as the hourly mails?

Tags: linux, logs, logcheck

I'm looking for a way to get logcheck to send the hourly notifications but also send me daily digest at the end of the day.

Is there a way to achieve that at all? It'd be fine to invoke logcheck manually for example. I'm not afraid of a little shell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

logcheck keeps track of where it is in the log files using a state directory. This can be overridden on the command line.

You might want to run the daily report as prerotate script in the rsyslog or syslog logrotate script. You will need to specify an alternate state directory on the command line.

To find the options for logcheck  run the command `/usr/sbin/logcheck -h` as any user other than root.